# Examples of non-abelian, non-isomorphic groups that have the same conjugacy class structure.

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

What groups of the same order are not isomorphic but contain the same conjugacy class structure?

A bit more detailed question is: Are there examples where those groups are non-abelian?

The only (abelian) example I know is $Z_2 \times Z_2 \times Z_2$ and $Z_8$ which both have conjugacy classes of $$8 = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1.$$

Comment: Any two non-isomorphic abelian groups of the same order will do.

Comment: Does that mean all non-isomorphic groups have same conjugacy class equation? I am trying to see if we can what groups can be concluded isomorphic based on similar conjugacy class equations.

Comment: Well, since in an abelian group *all* the conjugacy classes are trivial (i.e., only contain one element), their class equation is just a sum of ones.

Comment: What does "contain the same isomorphic class" mean?

Comment: I apologize, that was a typo. I meant to put conjugacy classes. The typo has been fixed.

Comment: What does "contain the same conjugacy class" mean? Does it mean 1) that they have the same number of conjugacy classes, 2) that the multisets of sizes of the conjugacy classes are the same (which is the interpretation being used by Nicky Hekster), or something else?

Comment: 2. The class equation has the sum of integers based on the size of the conjugacy classes of that group. In other words I am looking for the conjugacy classes of two groups of the same size. For abelian groups the elements form their own conjugacy class creating a sum of 1's.

Comment: You came back to edit --- did you not see the answer that was posted some days back? Does it not answer your question? Might you consider accepting it bny clicking the check box next to it, if it does answer your question?

Answer (score 4):

Example: the quaternion group $Q$ of order $8$ and the dihedral group $D_4$ of order $8$ have the same conjugacy class structure $(1+1+2+2+2)$, yet these non-abelian groups are not isomorphic.